# good twitter4j documentation

Tags: twitter, coldfusion, oauth, twitter4j

I have been trying to mess with the twitter4j library for some time now, and cannot seem to get it to work.

The web site and documentation there has proven to be less than helpful, and all the resources I have been able to dig up are really old and most likely irrelevant.

Does anyone have any good resources on this stuff (right now, the oauth portion of it)?  I am also trying to use this library via Coldfusion, if that makes a difference.

I have been able to create a (what I believe to be) valid request token and url (as I can get to twitter and login), but when I use the tokens that come back to reconstruct an access token later, it always bombs out with some kind of error...

Comment: Seriously, are people completely averse to using the <shift> key?  Capitalize!

Comment: +1. But at least it contained whole words and was not written like a text message. That is my biggest gripe ;)

Comment: @jzimmerman2011 - Not sure why this was down voted. But what resources have you tried? IIRC http://riaforge.org has several projects involving twitter and/or oauth. Also, posting a snippet of code and the actual error message would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the official doc is explaining only basic usages.
Twitter4J is best explained at the example codes located in twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/.

And the community is very active and you can expect getting answers promptly.
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#mailingList